# Xamarin.iOS native crash

Tags: xamarin.ios, mono

After a painstaking process of trying to reproduce the following crash, I finally managed to, though it still doesn't tell me exactly where it's occurring or what's causing it (although I do have a suspicion, see below). Needless to say, it's not a frequent occurrence, but strangely enough, adding new features to this production version of the app (such as using a derived UIApplication class), seems to make it crash with the same error bit more frequently.

I extracted this crash log from the iOS simulator I was testing on. Testing on a real device generates the same error.

```
IPad[1085]: critical: Stacktrace:
IPad[1085]: critical:   at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
IPad[1085]: critical:   at (wrapper managed-to-native) ObjCRuntime.Messaging.void_objc_msgSend_CATransform3D (intptr,intptr,CoreAnimation.CATransform3D) [0x0000b] in <21d68dce9d574fa1a5570d0bc0bc7703>:0
IPad[1085]: critical:   at CoreAnimation.CALayer.set_Transform (CoreAnimation.CATransform3D) [0x0000b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4991/8a391069/source/xamarin-macios/src/build/ios/native/CoreAnimation/CALayer.g.cs:2231
IPad[1085]: critical:   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.VisualElementTracker/<>c__DisplayClass23_0.<OnUpdateNativeControl>b__0 () [0x003c3] in C:\BuildAgent2\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\VisualElementTracker.cs:210
IPad[1085]: critical:   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.CADisplayLinkTicker.StartThread () [0x0001d] in C:\BuildAgent2\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\CADisplayLinkTicker.cs:64
IPad[1085]: critical:   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context (object) [0x00014] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/10.12.3.3/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/thread.cs:68
iPad[1085]: critical:   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal (System.Threading.ExecutionContext,System.Threading.ContextCallback,object,bool) [0x00071] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/10.12.3.3/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/executioncontext.cs:957
IPad[1085]: critical:   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run (System.Threading.ExecutionContext,System.Threading.ContextCallback,object,bool) [0x00000] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/10.12.3.3/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/executioncontext.cs:904
IPad[1085]: critical:   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run (System.Threading.ExecutionContext,System.Threading.ContextCallback,object) [0x0002b] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/10.12.3.3/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/executioncontext.cs:893
IPad[1085]: critical:   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart () [0x00008] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/10.12.3.3/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/thread.cs:105
IPad[1085]: critical:   at (wrapper runtime-invoke) object.runtime_invoke_void__this__ (object,intptr,intptr,intptr) [0x0004f] in <e9a408feb7af4c46b81589c1b3a3e1a6>:0

IPad[1085]: critical:  Native stacktrace:
IPad[1085]: critical:   0   IPad                  0x00000001059dda94 mono_handle_native_crash + 244
IPad[1085]: critical:   1   IPad                  0x00000001059e9b90 mono_sigsegv_signal_handler + 288
IPad[1085]: critical:   2   libsystem_platform.dylib            0x000000011273bb3a _sigtramp + 26
IPad[1085]: critical:   3   ???                                 0x000000000000ff6d 0x0 + 65389
IPad[1085]: critical:   4   QuartzCore                          0x000000010c7529ab _ZL18CAAnimation_setterP11CAAnimationj12_CAValueTypePKv + 169
IPad[1085]: critical:   5   QuartzCore                          0x000000010c74bd5a -[CAAnimation setDelegate:] + 30
IPad[1085]: critical:   6   UIKit                               0x00000001069b2c39 -[UIViewAnimationState setAnimationAttributes:correctZeroDuration:skipDelegateAssignment:customCurve:] + 1094
IPad[1085]: critical:   7   UIKit                               0x00000001069af475 -[UIViewAnimationState animationForLayer:forKey:forView:] + 1195
IPad[1085]: critical:   8   UIKit                               0x00000001069b0178 -[UIViewAnimationState actionForLayer:forKey:forView:] + 99
IPad[1085]: critical:   9   UIKit                               0x00000001069db52e +[UIView(Animation) _defaultUIViewActionForLayer:forKey:] + 111
IPad[1085]: critical:   10  UIKit                               0x00000001071b98ec -[UIView(UIKitManual) actionForLayer:forKey:] + 119
IPad[1085]: critical:   11  QuartzCore                          0x000000010c7224bc -[CALayer actionForKey:] + 437
IPad[1085]: critical:   12  QuartzCore                          0x000000010c71dade _ZL12actionForKeyP7CALayerPN2CA11TransactionEP8NSString + 76
IPad[1085]: critical:   13  QuartzCore                          0x000000010c71da6c _ZN2CA5Layer12begin_changeEPNS_11TransactionEjRP11objc_object + 140
IPad[1085]: critical:   14  QuartzCore                          0x000000010c71de04 _ZN2CA5Layer6setterEj12_CAValueTypePKv + 164
IPad[1085]: critical:   15  QuartzCore                          0x000000010c71f371 -[CALayer setTransform:] + 68
IPad[1085]: critical:   16  IPad                  0x0000000105b8fc89 xamarin_dyn_objc_msgSend + 217
IPad[1085]: critical:   17  ???                                 0x000000012b3cebcb 0x0 + 5020380107
IPad[1085]: critical:   18  ???                                 0x000000012b3ce9c9 0x0 + 5020379593
IPad[1085]: critical:   19  ???                                 0x000000012b187d49 0x0 + 5017992521
IPad[1085]: critical:   20  ???                                 0x000000012cabe3d4 0x0 + 5044429780
IPad[1085]: critical:   21  ???                                 0x000000012aa00f39 0x0 + 5010100025
IPad[1085]: critical:   22  IPad                  0x00000001059ecab5 mono_jit_runtime_invoke + 1301
IPad[1085]: critical:   23  IPad                  0x0000000105aa0dc8 do_runtime_invoke + 88
IPad[1085]: critical:   24  IPad                  0x0000000105ae0fce start_wrapper + 718
IPad[1085]: critical:   25  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000011274d93b _pthread_body + 180
IPad[1085]: critical:   26  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000011274d887 _pthread_body + 0
IPad[1085]: critical:   27  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000011274d08d thread_start + 13
IPad[1085]: critical: 
    =================================================================
    Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code. This usually indicates
    a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
    used by your application.
    =================================================================
```

I notice that in that log, there's a call to `UIViewAnimationState setAnimationAttributes:correctZeroDuration:skipDelegateAssignment:customCurve:`. 
This was at least consistent with how the app seems to crash (in the rare instances that it does). It always seems to while animating a view. In this particular instance, it was while the keyboard was appearing after tapping into an input field.

So I searched through the code to find where animation is being done, and I found this:

```
private void OnKeyboardNotification(NSNotification notification)
{
    if (!IsViewLoaded)
    {
        return;
    }

    // Check if keyboard is becoming visible
    bool visible = notification.Name == UIKeyboard.WillShowNotification;

    // Start an animation using values from the keyboard notification
    UIView.BeginAnimations("Animate for keyboard");
    UIView.SetAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState(true);
    UIView.SetAnimationDuration(UIKeyboard.AnimationDurationFromNotification(notification));
    UIView.SetAnimationCurve((UIViewAnimationCurve)UIKeyboard.AnimationCurveFromNotification(notification));

    var keyboardFrame = visible ? UIKeyboard.FrameEndFromNotification(notification) : UIKeyboard.FrameBeginFromNotification(notification);

    OnKeyboardChanged(visible, (float)keyboardFrame.Height);

    UIView.CommitAnimations();
}

protected virtual void OnKeyboardChanged(bool visible, float keyboardHeight)
{

}
```

Like I said, still doesn't tell me *exactly* what's causing the crash, so...

**Question:**
What exactly is causing the crash?

Version info:

```
=== Visual Studio Community 2017 for Mac ===
Version 7.2.2 (build 11)
Runtime: Mono 5.4.1.6 (2017-06/1f4613aa1ac) (64-bit)

=== .NET Core ===
Runtime Version: 1.0.1
SDK Version: 1.0.0-preview2-003131

=== Xamarin.iOS ===
Version: 10.12.3.3 (Visual Studio Community)

=== iOS ===
Version: 10.3

=== Test device ===
iPad Pro (9.7 inch)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to wrap that process in

```
try {

} catch (Exception ex) {

};
```

And put a breakpoint into the catch, then look up the ex object to get more information on what caused that crash.

My advice for future will be to warp `int main[]` function into try-catch, so you can automatically get any crash that your app throws from a native code :)

Comment: That was one of the first things I tried. An exception never gets caught, most likely because it is being caught and handled natively somewhere...followed by an abort/crash.

Comment: the thing is, that native is running under Mono VM, so if you put try{} catch to int main[] function, mono will catch any native crash :)

Comment: Except it doesn't. This is what my `Main` function looks like: `public class Application { static void Main(string[] args) { try {UIApplication.Main(args, null, "AppDelegate");} catch (Exception exc) { // never gets to here } } }`

Comment: @Ash strangely,,,